# SQL Server T-Sql Convert filetime to datetime

Tags: t-sql

I need to convert a filetime field value to datetime format through t-sql in SQL Server

I have applied following formula to do so which works absolutely fine for positive values (>0). But somehow this formula does not work for negative values and it return null value.

```
SELECT LastModifiedTime,
       CASE WHEN LastModifiedTime <= 1 THEN NULL
       ELSE DATEADD(ms,
                    ((LastModifiedTime) / CAST(10000 AS bigint)) % 86400000,
                    DATEADD(day, (LastModifiedTime) / CAST(864000000000 AS bigint) - 109207, 0))
       END AS Expr1
FROM TableName
```

Sample value i had tried were:

- **-9094352270227314699**  (negative value which did not work)
- **129046581660000000**   (positive value which works)

Comment: Where are you seeing a negative value for a timestamp?

Comment: This value is stored in database whose column type bigInt. This has been put there with a third party software.

Answer (score 1):

CASE WHEN LastModifiedTime <= 1 THEN NULL

It's doing what  you told it to do.

Comment: Because I was not aware how to convert to DateTime when the value was -ve, I returned a NULL value. Can you help me as of how to convert to DateTime when the value is -ve?